# Why path is so defined?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading definition of "path in topological space X", which is as follows:

" A **path** from a point $x$ to a point $y$ in a topological $X$ is a continuous function $f$ from the unit interval $[0,1]$ to $X$ with $f(0) = x$ and $f(1) = y$ "

My question is, why is path so defined? Why the choosen interval is $[0,1]$? Can't we take $[2,3]$? Why is the function taken to be continuous? Is the reason behind this, is that "path must be connected"? I am beiginner in topology! and to be obvious, anyone who does want to clear his concepts in topology, must know it! and, I don't want to "memories the definition without understanding it"  as some people do!! Please help me...:-)

Comment: The interval $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[2,3]$, so sure.  You could define a path a that way.  There is nothing particularly special about $[0,1]$; any closed, bounded interval will get the job done (since, again, they are all homeomorphic to each other).

Comment: when you hear the word "path" what comes to your mind first?

Comment: @Anubhav, I think "way of approach from point 'x' to point 'y'

Comment: @Xander sir, anubhav sir, could you elaborate? Why function taken to be continuous? Is due to the reason, that I had mention in the question? Further could you provide an example with different paths on same points.

Comment: Intuitively, a path is supposed to be something like a path that a particle could follow to get from point A to point B. So it should be continuous because a particle's position can't jump around discontinuously.

Comment: Think about what your intuition about path is.  You might think of it as the set of points that a particle travels through, starting at some point at some initial time and ending at some (possibly different point) at some final time.  We expect that the particle doesn't jump around (hence continuity), and we have have a start and end time (hence the interval).

Comment: If you study further you will see that there are properties called "path-connected" (or "path-wise connected") and "connected". A  space may or may not be connected. Path-connected spaces are connected spaces, but there are connected spaces that are not path-connected.